# Sum widths of li (first lvl) elements in "each loop"

Tags: jquery

I would like to sum widths of li elements, but only first lvl of li in ul.

My list:

HTML

```
<ul id="top_menu">
    <li>1a</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1
       <ul>
           <li>2</li>
           <li>2</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1
       <ul>
           <li>2</li>
           <li>2</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
var menu3 = 0;

$('ul#top_menu > li').each(function() {
    menu3 +=  $('ul#top_menu > li').outerWidth(true);
});

alert("Total Width is " + menu3);
```

But this code sums only first element 6 times.

Regards

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using `this` variable for calculating width?

Comment: nope, there's no reason... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `this` object inside the each function for calculating the width.

```js
var menu3 = 0;

$('ul#top_menu > li').each(function() {
    menu3 +=  $(this).outerWidth(true);
});

alert("Total Width is " + menu3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="top_menu">
    <li>1a</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1
       <ul>
       <li>2</li>
       <li>2</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1
       <ul>
       <li>2</li>
       <li>2</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much :)